# Problema al insertar un error MySQLi en una BBDD MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de logs, con PHP, SQL y BBDD MySQL. El caso es que quiero que cuando alguna consulta (o cualquier funcionalidad del sistema) falle, se inserte en una tabla de MySQL el tipo de error que ha sido. Para aprender a hacerlo, estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba, antes de implementarlo en todo el programa.

Aquí el código:

```
$id=0;

    $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csvs` SET `insercion_articulos_csv`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$id";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);    

    if($resultado){
        echo "La inserción se realiza de forma adecuada";
    } else {
        $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `insercion_articulos_csv`=".mysqli_error($conWebService)." WHERE `id`=$id";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        var_dump(mysqli_error($conWebService));
        var_dump($resultado);
        echo "La inserción no se realiza de forma adecuada";
    }
```

La primera sentencia `UPDATE` está mal a propósito, ya que el nombre de la tabla no es correcto. Ahora mismo en pantalla me imprime lo siguiente:

```
string(216) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table 'practicas.logs_articulos_api_csvs' doesn't exist WHERE `id`=1' at line 1"
bool(false)
La inserción no se realiza de forma adecuada
```

Sin embargo, no me mete el error en la BBDD que es lo que realmente quiero. ¿Dónde puede estar el fallo? Muchas gracias, saludos.

P.D. Estos campos de error en la tabla los tengo definidos como de tipo `longtext`, no sé si puede influir en algo.

Comment: Como bien dice @Excorpion en su respuesta, tendrías que hacer un `INSERT` en el `else` para que el error se registre en la BD. Te recomendaría que uses consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código y optimizarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recree tu problema en mi base de datos, y obtuve lo siguiente:

- Primero que nada, cuando guardas el error, no estas haciendo una inserción, estás haciendo un `UPDATE`. Si en la tabla de errores, no existe el `id=0`, no podrá actualizar. Asi mismo si fuese cualquier otro id. Lo mejor sería cambiar eso por un `INSERT`.
- Segundo, el problema que encontré al querer guardar el dato, es que el string de error, sea `mysqli_error($conWebService)` de quien hablamos. Contiene comillas (`''`), las cuales, en mi caso, interfirieron durante la inserción de datos. Por lo que decidí deshacerme de ellas haciendo un `str_replace` luego de rescatar el error en una variable

A fin de cuentas, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
$sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csvs` SET `insercion_articulos_csv`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$id";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);      

if($resultado){
    echo "La inserción se realiza de forma adecuada";
} else {
    $error = mysqli_error($conexion);
    $error = str_replace("'", "", $error);
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `logs_articulos_api_csv`(`insercion_articulos_csv`) VALUES ('".$error."')";
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
    echo "</br> La inserción no se realiza de forma adecuada";
}
```

---

Resultado de mi intento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]